# Alfresco commmunity 5.1 custom task variable

Tags: alfresco

I'm using activiti engine shipped with alfresco communtiy edition 5.1,
I want to create a custom variable to be used when creating task items on a workflow.
The custom variable is a complex variable,I want to know how to define a new variable model, so that the tasks can be searchable through the variable values

Comment: Do you mean using a custom task model (http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/wf-task-model.html) ?

Comment: I want to create complex variables, in other words objects (lists or arrays)not using the simple types that's is the problem and then use them as parameters when searching tasks